# GWT setInnerSafeHtml rendering HTML source

Tags: html, gwt

I am working on an application which fetches HTML content from the server and displays it to the user. The content fetched from the server is a complete HTML document. I have used UiBinder to specify UI for the view.

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="mainPanel" styleName="ap-mainPanel">
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In the view I have setViewerContent(String content) method:

```
public void setViewerContent( String content )
{
    mainPanel.setStyleName( "ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel" ); //$NON-NLS-1$
    SafeHtml safeHtmlContent = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString( content );
    mainPanel.getElement().setInnerSafeHtml(safeHtmlContent);
}
```

When I run this I am seeing the source of the HTML document with all the markups. If I use setInnerHtml() then the document is displayed correctly. Static Code Analysis rules for the code base do not allow usage of setInnerHtml(). Can someone suggest any remedies ?

Answer (score 1):

From [the javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlUtils.html#fromString(java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a `SafeHtml` containing the **escaped** string.

You'll want to use `fromTrustedString` if you trust your server, or [`SimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitizeHtml()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SimpleHtmlSanitizer.html#sanitizeHtml(java.lang.String)) (or your own HTML sanitizer) if you don't.